# Should we use a single quote to include or exclude NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which between the queries is correct if you want to exclude NULL values. The ones with a single quote or without quotes? NULL isn't a string, it's actually blank but I just want to make sure.

```
select [Gross Amt], * from [EDW].[vw_Data]
where  [Sic_Code] <> 'NULL'

select [Gross Amt], * from [EDW].[vw_Data]
where  [Sic_Code] <> NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `IS NULL`  or `IS NOT NULL` operators instead. Comparison operators (=, !=, <>) always return NULL when handle with NULL. Using <> NULL in WHERE clause *acts like FALSE* and returns nothing.

```
SELECT [Gross Amt], * 
FROM [EDW].[vw_Data]
WHERE [Sic_Code] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Technically they return NULL but they usually _act like_ false (e.g. in the `WHERE` clause above no records will be returned)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just wanted to describe for people who use simple logic (true, false). SQL has (true, false, NULL) :)

Comment: @BongReyes If it help you, consider marking as answer :)